# ActiveRecord: Combining Two *COMPLEX* ActiveRecord Results

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, select, activerecord, union

I have a SQL query that utilizes UNION and I'm trying to change it into an ActiveRecord Query. It goes as follows:

```
(SELECT town FROM town_health_records 
  WHERE percent_publicly_financed_prenatal_care_2005_to_2008 IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY percent_publicly_financed_prenatal_care_2005_to_2008 
      DESC LIMIT 10)
        UNION 
          (SELECT town 
            FROM town_health_records 
              WHERE total_infant_deaths_2005_to_2008 IS NOT NULL 
                AND 
                  town != 'Massachusetts Total' 
                    ORDER BY total_infant_deaths_2005_to_2008 
                      DESC LIMIT 10);
```

I have been trying something, but it doesn't seem to work (Spaced for ease of use):

```
TownHealthRecord.select("town")
  .where("percent_publicly_financed_prenatal_care_2005_to_2008 IS NOT NULL")
    .order("percent_publicly_financed_prenatal_care_2005_to_2008")
      .union(TownHealthRecord.select("town")
        .where("total_infant_deaths_2005_to_2008 IS NOT NULL AND town !=        
          'Massachusetts Total'")
            .order("total_infant_deaths_2005_to_2008")
              .first(10))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no UNION support in a standard ActiveRecord. You can use find_by_sql method, or make a view in your database